# Finding dynamic range of rotation matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How do I theoretically calculate the maximum value of the transformed output can reach after transforming a vector? If it is an eigen vector then the eigen value will tell the max scaling possible, but if it is not eigen vector then what can be the max output ?

The matrix is Discrete cosine transform (DCT). What will be max co-ordinates of a vector after transforming with DCT ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, rotation matrices don't scale, so the length of all vectors acted upon by matrix will keep their lengths. Are you talking about the maximum value of a given coordinate of the vector?

Comment: Yes, what is the maximum value the given vector co-ordinate can reach after rotational transform. Is it the linear combination of basis vectors ?